# Set margin dynamically

Tags: java, android, layout, native

I am trying to make the statusbar translucent, but dont want, that the content of my activity is hiding behind it.
-> I have to set the top margin dynamically...

I have tried it like that:
MainActivty.java:

```
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                int x = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplyWindowInsets: " + x);
                //newLayoutParams.topMargin = x;

                //newLayoutParams.setMargins(0,x,0,0);
                view.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
                return insets;
            }
        });
        setContentView(view);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    }
```

Sadly this does not work.
Error message:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rxstudios.rxmusic2, PID: 6324
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
at com.rxstudios.rxmusic2.MainActivity.onAttachedToWindow(MainActivity.java:77)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onAttachedToWindow(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:129)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onAttachedToWindow(DecorView.java:1537)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18347)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

How else would I do this if it doesn't let me get my Constraintlayout like that?
Since it is a constraintlayout, I thought about getting the first child of it, which is a fragment. Can I set the margin to the fragment? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

change code :

```
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        View view = findViewById(R.id.content).getRootView();
        // TODO: 2021/5/17  
//        WindowManager.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
 
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                int x = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplyWindowInsets: " + x);
                //newLayoutParams.topMargin = x;

                //newLayoutParams.setMargins(0,x,0,0);
                view.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
                return insets;
            }
        });
        setContentView(view);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

Or dont change the java code, change the view of R.id.content to LinearLayout